# LSTM model does not learn a simple pattern

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm a noob in ML, and tried to write an LSTM model that will process batches of sequences and will detect the following simple pattern: If a sequence starts with an odd number then the target is 0 otherwise it is 1:

data:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 2  3  4]
  [ 3  4  5]
  [ 4  5  6]
  [ 5  6  7]] #starts with 1 -> 0

 [[ 6  7  8]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [ 8  9 10]
  [ 9 10 11]
  [10 11 12]] #starts with 6 -> 1

 [[11 12 13]
  [12 13 14]
  [13 14 15]
  [14 15 16]
  [15 16 17]]] #starts with 11 -> 0
```

target:

```
[0 1 0]
```

code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras import callbacks
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.utils import shuffle


def demo():
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    dummy_data = pd.DataFrame(data=[[x, x+1, x+2, int((x - 1) / 5 % 2)] for x in range(1, 1001)],
                              columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'target'])

    dummy_data[['a', 'b', 'c']] = scaler.fit_transform(dummy_data[['a', 'b', 'c']])
    data = dummy_data.loc[:, dummy_data.columns != 'target']
    target = dummy_data['target']
    data = np.array(np.split(data.values, 200))
    target = np.array(np.split(target.values, 200))
    data, target = shuffle(data, target)
    target = np.array(list(map(lambda x: x[0],target)))
    print(data[:3,:],target[:3])
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, target, test_size=0.25, random_state=4)

    opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0005, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0001)
    # build the model
    model = Sequential()


    num_features = data.shape[2]
    num_samples = data.shape[1]

    first_lstm = LSTM(32, batch_input_shape=(None, num_samples, num_features), return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')
    model.add(
        first_lstm)
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LSTM(16, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(LSTM(8, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(LeakyReLU())
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.summary()

    tb = callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs/', histogram_freq=10,
                               batch_size=128,
                               write_graph=True, write_grads=True, write_images=False,
                               embeddings_freq=0, embeddings_layer_names=None, embeddings_metadata=None)

    loss_checkpoint = callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('./best_loss.hdf5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True,
                                                mode='min')

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=5000, validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                        callbacks=[tb, loss_checkpoint])


demo()
```

I'm expecting the net to learn this simple pattern however it fails, see the loss below:
[image]

What could be improved, in order for the network to perform better?

Comment: LSTM works good with sequences. With your example, maybe, you can try something more simple - for instance, a simple NN with 2-3 hidden layers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my example uses sequences of 5, and that's what I'm trying to learn

Answer (score 0):

According to the your comment, I would suggest to change dataset. Try something like:

data:

```
[
    [1, 3, 5],
    [2, 4, 6],
    [3, 5, 7]
]
```

target:`[1, 0, 1]`

You should try dataset with a more pronounced pattern in the sequence. In theory, LSTM should perform better for such samples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but my goal is different, i.e: I want to label the entire batch as 1 if it starts with an odd number (`[[1,3,5] , [2,4,6] , [3,5,7]] -> 1`)